# What is difference between Vim's clipboard "unnamed" and "unnamedplus" settings?

Tags: vim, clipboard

What is the difference between these 2 settings?

```
set clipboard=unnamed
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

Which one should I use in order to have multi-platform .vimrc?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

On Mac OS X and Windows, the `*` and `+` registers both point to the system clipboard so `unnamed` and `unnamedplus` have the same effect: the unnamed register is synchronized with the system clipboard.

On Linux, you have essentially two clipboards: one is pretty much the same as in the other OSes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in other programs, mapped to register `+` in Vim), the other is the "selection" clipboard (mapped to register `*` in Vim).

Using only `unnamedplus` on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X allows you to:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in other programs and put in Vim with `p` on all three platforms,
- yank in Vim with `y` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in other programs on all three platforms.

If you also want to use Linux's "selection" clipboard, you will also need `unnamed`.

Here is a cross-platform value:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

Reference:

```
:h 'clipboard'
(and follow the tags)
```

Comment: What is the difference here vs `^=` & `+=`? I understand from reading the vim help sections, that `^` multiplies values and `+` adds values, so to me it seems like `+` should be used, but I don't pretend to understand vim.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, Vim as three types of options: "string", "number", and "boolean". `^=` multiplies only in the context of "number" options but `'clipboard'` is a "string" option where `^=` *prepends* the value and `+=` *appends* the value.

Comment: Thank you! I went with your solution: https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/linuxTweaks/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: `"*` is the one similar to ctrl+c. `"+` is the X selection buffer.

Comment: So, for Neovim: `vim.opt.clipboard:append { 'unnamed', 'unnamedplus' }`